# INNO Setup [CODE] block, set status?

Tags: activex, inno-setup

I have an installer that needs to install some visual c++ redistributables before anything else gets installed.  This is because an ActiveX COM object wont register without it being installed first.

I have the code that properly installs the visual c++, but the program seems to hang for a minute (to the user) while it is installing since they have no clue what is happening.  Is there any way to inform the user what i am doing without popping up an actual messagebox? Like how you can set the status in the [Run] block.

```
// This function will be called after the last "Next" button is pressed, but before any files get installed
procedure DoPreInstall();
var
    ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
    Exec(ExpandConstant('vcredist_x86_2008.exe'), '/q', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode)
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it but I found this: http://news.jrsoftware.org/news/innosetup.code/msg21747.html.

It might help.  Another is to run the vcredist in a non-silent mode.

Comment: I was able to include this iss file, and call it directly. Work's great. Thanks.